# deleteRowsAtIndexPaths resets custom cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm relatively new to Swift and iOS and I have one issue - I have a custom SwipeCell class that extends UITableViewCell. It's a cell that can be swiped left and right, and has buttons on each side. For some reason if I made the buttons out of the frame of the cell when user swipes the cell they would appear but could not call an action, so my solution was to make cell wider than it is (so buttons can fit in it). Because it was done this way my cell has to have an offset by default for the total width of the buttons of the left (let's say 100), so it's position is X:-100.

And that's fine, and everything works fines with the cells, however there is one huge issue - if I call the deletion of any cell from the tableView like this

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([tableView.indexPathForCell(activeCell)!], withRowAnimation: .None)
```

tableView then deletes the cell, and all of the other cells that are currently visible (doesn't happen with cells above or below the screen bounds) get moved to X:0 instead of staying at X:-100, so I assume that deleteRowsAtIndexPaths calls some function that resets the visible cells positions to 0,0. I'm currently setting swipe cells positions with layoutSubviews() since the number of buttons is dynamic and couldn't be determined upfront, but layoutSubviews is not the function where the bug happens.

So to sum up question - what function does deleteRowsAtIndexPaths call after deleting a cell that resets/redraws the visible cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could find out what happens inside of deleteRowAtIndexPaths, and why it changes frames of each Cell, I decided to just do my own function that deletes a row, by obtaining cells with tableView.visibleCells, and then just moving cells bellow the deleted cell up by a height of deleted cell. Thank you all for trying to help me, and especially thanks to Abhinav who told me that it was handled internally, which help me decide to write a custom code for the deletion.

Answer (score 1):

`deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` deletes a row(s) from the tableView. This is handled internally by iOS. From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:):

> Deletes the rows specified by an array of index paths, with an option
>   to animate the deletion.

Another interesting thing to note here is that this method does not modify your model (object that holds data used by your table view cells to render on themselves). You have to do that yourself. The cells are deleted, but if you call reloadData without deleting the row from your Model, cell will reappear.

Comment: Not sure if you understood me - I don't have a problem with reappearing of the cell, the cell disappears, but all other cells get shifted (deleteRowsAtIndexPaths for some reason changes their frame to the same size, but 0,0 coordinates instead of -100,0 where they were). So the problem is that deleteRowsAtIndexPaths actually calls some method, or moves the frame by itself.

Comment: I answered that in my first line. This is handled by iOS framework internally.

Comment: I understand that it affects the cell it deletes, and that it moves cells below up, but why would it affect other cells (like the ones above), and why would it move them on X axis? Is it possible that it doesn't call some function like layoutSubviews once it does that on the UIView element (specifically UITableViewCell)?

Answer (score 0):

Expect that cells get deleted and created all the time. Cells are very, very temporary objects. Write the code to create one when needed, and don't make any assumptions. Don't assume the cell is there later, don't assume it's in the same row, don't assume it displays the same data (because cells are recycled).

Comment: What does the thing you wrote have to do with my question? I've made a custom SwipeCell that extends UITableViewCell, and it overrides layoutSubviews() func, and inside of it calls super.layoutSubviews() and then adds custom button afterwards (if they aren't present yet, since layoutSubviews can be called on existing cell). The problem here is that layoutSubviews gets called for other visible cells when one cell has been deleted and it sets the X position of each cell to -100, but for some reason, something gets called afterwards (in core itself) that moves cells X to 0.

Comment: So my question is upon deletion is there something else that gets called except layoutSubviews for visible cells?